# Java Double Format to show 2 decimal points even when zero

Tags: java, double, decimal, decimalformat

I want to print out double values onto the screen with 2 decimal points. So far this line has worked perfectly:

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("$#,###.##").format(value));
```

For inputs like:

```
double value = 82348238482834.23482348;
```

It prints out:

```
$82,348,238,482,834.23
```

Which is exactly what I want. However, if I have the input `0` I want it to print out `$0.00`. With the above format line it prints out `$0`. I tried changing the above code to:

```
double value = 0;
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00").format(value));
```

But that printed out `$.00`. I could just do this:

```
if(value == 0) {
    System.out.println("$0.00");
}
```

It works but it's very ugly. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Well yes, `0` *always* prints, `#` only *conditionally* prints... so which do you think you want just before the point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00").format(value));
```

Changed:

```
"$#,##0.00"
```

**Like Jon said, 0 indicates a digit so it includes zero, # indicates a digit but zero shows as absent.**

For more info on [DecimalFormat.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why people still use this `DecimalFormat` stuff. To achieve what you want just use `System.out.printf` with the following pattern.

```
System.out.printf("%,.2f%n", value);
```

If the value is `0` it will be always printed as `0.00` or `0,00` depending on locale.